# Spatial polygons with messed up shape

Tags: r, polygon, openstreetmap, spatial, r-sp

I am new to spatial data. My goal is to get the `gpx` files from [openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Hungary/Boundaries#J.C3.A1r.C3.A1sok) and plot polygons of Hungary's boundaries. I could successfully plot the boundaries under `Járások` but there are some boundaries under `Kistérségek` which are messed up, containing loops between points.

### Image

[image: Plot of kistérségek]

### Reproducable example for a specific boundary

```
library(XML)
library(magrittr)
library(sp)

parsed <- xmlParse("http://osmrm.openstreetmap.de/gpx.jsp?relation=1368104") %>% xmlToList()
coord <- do.call(rbind, parsed$rte)
name <- coord[1, 1]
coord <- coord[-(1:2), ]
coord <- apply(coord, 2, as.numeric)

poly <- Polygons(list(Polygon(coord)), name)
sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(poly), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(sp)
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Is the error because I missed something, or is it simply an issue with openstreetmap data? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you're interested in the border polygons, I can recommend the `getData` function from the `raster` package. I just ran `hun <- getData(country='HUN',level=2); plot(hun)` and everything looks fine

Comment: Does R perform sorting on the ways belonging to the polygon (relation)? Relations in OSM can consist of ways that are unsorted. The sorting has to be performed by the end user.

Comment: @Val: thanks, I first used the `GADM` solution, but I thought it might not be up-to-date because both `openstreetmap` and the data I got from a company mentioned some areas that are not part of the GADM data. (Such as `Budaörsi kistérség`)

I just checked that these areas are not included now, so I guess using GADM is fine, however I am still curious about this issue, so I'll leave the question open for now.

Comment: you may want to try using https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata or `sf::st_read` (using the GDAL OSM driver); `sf` contains a function `st_is_valid` which checks whether polygons are valid (not self-intersecting); `st_buffer` with buffer size zero sometimes helps making them valid.

Comment: Your polygons are 'messed up' because there is no definition of where one polygon ends and the next one starts. All the lat/lon coordinates you have are in a single matrix, so they are assumed to be one continuous line. So the plot you have is essentially a single line.

Comment: @EdzerPebesma Thank you, I will check them out!

Comment: @SymbolixAU That shouldn't be the case, because as you can see on the second image, it is a single polygon and it's self-intersecting.